# Loop for object n HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My code is quite simple. I only want to add John and Marie to my table.
Works great but my issue is if there is no John and Marie I want to create a row and show a `-` in my td.

How do I know if there was not added any row when the ng-repeat ends?

```html
<tr class="text-center" ng-if="name == 'John' || name == 'Marie'" ng-repeat="name in vm.names track by $index">
  <td>{{name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ng-switch directive:

```
<tr class="text-center" ng-switch"name" ng-repeat="name in vm.names track by $index">
  <td ng-switch-when="John">{{name}}</td>
  <td ng-switch-when="Marie">{{name}}</td>
  <td ng-switch-when="Paul">{{name}}</td>
  <td ng-switch-default>-</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I dont think it works. If names is John, Marie, Paul it will add 2 rows and then a empty one. I only want to add a empty with `-` if there is no John and Marie in vm.names

Comment: Sorry, I see your point. Then try the ng-switch directive. I updated my answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could map your original object in the controller with something like this:

```
this.names = this.names.map(name => { 
  name ? name : '-'; 
})
```